# Handle URL from onCreateWindow WebView

Tags: android, webview

Can I get URL from calling `onCreateWindow` on `WebView`?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture,
        Message resultMsg) {

}
```

Comment: Note: in some cases the URL is not enough to load the new window correctly. There may be other links between the original and the new window, they may need to exchange messages. In that case it seems you have to use the recommended approach of `transport.setWebView(newWebView); resultMessage.sendToTarget();` in the same activity as the original webview.

Answer (score 14):

You can get clicked URL by using this code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture,
        Message resultMsg) {
    Message href = view.getHandler().obtainMessage();
    view.requestFocusNodeHref(href);

    String url = href.getData().getString("url");
    handleUrl(url); // handle the url here

    return super.onCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
}
```

Comment: Often returns `null` vlaue

Comment: sometimes got javascript method call

Comment: `href.getData()` is always an empty bundle so always getting null for url key. Any other way?

Comment: have you got any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture,
        Message resultMsg) {
    Logger.d(Constants.TAG, "onCreateWindow"+resultMsg);
    WebView targetWebView = new WebView(getActivity()); // pass a context
    targetWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                handleWebViewLinks(url); // you can get your target url here
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
    });
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(targetWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A version of [albeee's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371661/1587892) solution that doesn't need to start loading the web page:

```
@override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    Logger.d(Constants.TAG, "onCreateWindow"+resultMsg);
    WebView targetWebView = new WebView(getActivity()); // pass a context
    targetWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {                   handleWebViewLinks(url); // you can get your target url here
            return true; // return false if you want the load to continue
        }
    });
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(targetWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
    return true;
}
```