# Android - Open target _blank links in WebView with external browser

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I build a `WebView` which displays a website. The website contains links without a `target="_blank"` attribute and some with it.

I need to open the links with `target` defined in the external standard device browser and the ones without it inside the WebView.

I'm using a `WebViewClient` and I tried around with this function but still all my links are opened within the `WebView`:

Alternative 1:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);        
}
```

Alternative 2:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;        
}
```

Does anybody know how I can open blank-links externally?

Thanks!

PS: To avoid missunderstandings: I can't use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17994750/1331671) because the only way I know the link should be opened externallly is the `target` attribute.

Comment: Have you got the answer when url contains the attribute target="_blank" ??

Answer (score 76, accepted):

After visiting the above links, I come up with this code and hope this helps.

```
wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
    {
        WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
        String data = result.getExtra();
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It is important to understand when does onCreateWindow triggers. Please see the [link](http://therockncoder.blogspot.in/2014/04/understanding-androids-webchromeclient.html) to understand better

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the regular webviewclient?

Comment: sometimes `data` is null

Comment: This solution is nearly perfect. Except that, the image within a <a> elements would be open in new window when the image is hit, while the <a> won't as expected.

Comment: How to handle the case where data is null?

Comment: @firebear: Facing the same issue, any solution yet?

Comment: This solution works okay, successfully logs onCreateWindow event when link has target=_"blank" but then when clicking all(?) instances of <a> would have the same behavior of new tab without calling the onCreateWindow event as @firebear mentioned above.

I found a clever solution by Lotzy. by concatting a tag onPageLoad then overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading that somehow works like a query string parameter.

here's the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002379/5447855

Comment: The docs say "This method should return true if the host application will create a new window".

Comment: open twitter can crash! because of  @Vlad 's said `sometimes data is null `.

Comment: data is null , please give the solution of it.

Comment: It had been 6 years since I answered this question and I don't write android code any more. Can anyone help with the `data == null` problem?

Answer (score 4):

I faced same problem. I wanted to open my web sites pages inside the application and rest all  the pages should be open in Default Browser. I used one technique. If URL contains my website name, then I opened it in WebView and rest all the websites opened in Default browser.

Find Below code, I hope It would be useful for  all who faced such problems.

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("/internetgeeks")) {
            browser.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Carson-ip's answer is better : it natively handles `target="_blank"` as asked.

Comment: Just to complement the answer, startActivity was not avaliable to me, I called `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and call the activity by `view.Context.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem and now I've found the solution.

You also need to use WebChromeClient.You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398162/how-to-have-android-webview-open-links-that-are-target-blank-within-an-iframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8828975/1376901) .
And you can set a WebViewClient to the new WebView and override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, then you can get the url and do whatever you want here. If you don't set the WebViewClient, I think it should works too. In my case I want to get the url so I set a WebViewClient to the new WebView.

By the way, if you remove the old webview then when you come back form the browser,the webview is blank. So I retained the webview and added a new one but set the visibility to "gone".

Answer (score 0):

```
private  WebView WEB_v;
```

**if you open new window when you click a link any 2nd window, then it I will open by another browser**

```
 WEB_v.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    WEB_v.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
        {
            WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
            String data = result.getExtra();
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
            context.startActivity(browserIntent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it using only Javascript, then this is my solution for opening any link from webview of the android or ios app to the external browser.

Modified your URL with this 'open=outside' in query params.

ie. https://example.com/homePage?open=outside