# Android WebView links to same window with target=_blank to open new window

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a hybrid app that uses WebView to render external html from my own site. It had a problem that if any link was clicked, it started a browser window. I found this code to help me out and it works:

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But now the problem is that I want it to not work for links that have target=_blank in them. So any normal links still open inside the WebView while the links with target=_blank should open in new browser window.

Any way we can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First,

`mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);`

Then in `WebChromeClient`, override `OnCreateWindow()`

```
    private class MyWebChromeclient extends WebChromeClient {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
            boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

            WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebViewActivity2.this);
            view.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I am afraid you did not understand it quite well. target=_blank is not something in the url, it is an attribute of the html anchor tag. Something like this:

<a href=http://www.example.com target=_blank>click here</a>

I thought it was obvious!

Comment: Changed the code, never worked on HTML, so figured this target thing after little searching. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, the new code does not resolve WebViewActivity2. Which package does it belong to?

Comment: This code is for reference, you need to use your own activity name here, or pass context of the app.

Comment: The code does not seem to work after I used my own activity name, etc. It did not give error but also did not achieve what I wanted. So I guess I will have to give up this method and simply use a hint that if the url contains a specific string (in my case "redirect"), then I use the old code you gave to initialize a browser intent and cancel this call. I hope it will work. I am accepting your answer for it did help me understand the thing. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy that it gave you idea, but wondering why this one did not work though. If you wish, you could try passing activity's context or put '`getBaseContext()` instead of this whole activityname.this

Comment: instead of WebViewActivity2.this you can just put ```view.getContext()```

Comment: @Darpan It is possible to achieve that without the `Action_View` only to open that url ?

Comment: @Spritzig ACTION_VIEW is needed so that Android can offer apps that can handle this content-type. In this case, browsers

Comment: This works for me. My Html is `<a href="http://url" target="_blank"><img src=".."/></a>`

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is never called for me here. any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

Try this.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
    {
        WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
        String data = result.getExtra();
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Reference: [Carson Ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser/23431369)

Comment: This really helped me, it was getHitTestResult().getExtra() I was missing to grab the URL. 
BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Using kotlin

```
myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
myWebView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
```

Answer (score 0):

One more setting required for webview in addition to myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
**myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);**

Comment: Should be:
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

Comment: Please correct it to **getStettings()** however it doesn't work