# Razorpay checkout form stuck on loading in webview

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, webview, razorpay

I have a webpage with Razorpay integrated and I want to use it in webview app. Everything works fine but when I select a payment method in razorpay form, it is stuck on loading and never opens the next screen where it asks whether to make it successful or fail (test mode).

Code:

```
var options = {
            "key": "rzp_test_UIYCZTZXgkmZtu",
            "amount": (totalAmount*100).toString(), // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
            "currency": "INR",
            "name": "test payment :)",
            "description": "Test Transaction",
            "image": Logo,
            "order_id": res.data.orderID,
            "handler": function (response){
                alert("payment successful! :)")
            },
            "prefill": {
                "name": "xyz",
                "email": "xyz@abc.com",
                "contact": "000000000"
            },
        }
        const paymentObject = new window.Razorpay(options)
        paymentObject.open()
```

It works in website but not in web view. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you loading the razorpay Script before opening the Modal?

Comment: It would be great if you could post the complete function for reference

Comment: Facing the same issue. Works fine in web browser, but inside webview, the test mock diaglog never shows up. Due to this, Netbanking payments are also not working as they open up a new window. I hope someone can reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partially working solution. The main problem is that the Razorpay dialog tries to open a new window to show the success / failure, and your webview is not allowing new windows to open.

On Android the following helps:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

If you would rather open the window in a separate webview, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27010225/583875

or in a separate browser, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029609