# Xamarin Android WebView don't fire navigating if "target=_blank"

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm using a webview in xamarin, i followed many tutorials to handle navigation, and all works fine.
My issue is : when an anchor tag has a target="_blank" the event Navigating is never fired.

I see arround someone give a javascript solution which remove target=_blank and attach it at the end of href link.

Is really that the right way to do that? Look wired..

Thank you

This is initialization in xamarin.android renderer

```
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        global::Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
        }            
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            Control.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.Settings.UserAgentString = Control.Settings.UserAgentString  + " crmvw";                
            Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient xCC = new CustChromeWebViewClient(_context);
            Control.SetWebChromeClient(xCC);
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new CrmWebViewClient(this, $"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));     
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");     
            Control.LoadUrl(((HybridWebView)Element).Uri);
        }
    }
```

And this is my navigating event, never fired when anchor has target=_blank

```
        private void webv_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFirstLoad) { 
            IsBusy = true;
            IsFirstLoad = false;
        }

        if (e.Url.ToLower().StartsWith("tel:") || e.Url.ToString().StartsWith("wtai:") || e.Url.ToLower().StartsWith("sms:") || e.Url.ToLower().StartsWith("mailto:"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

here my override function for URL in my custom WEBView

```
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, Android.Webkit.IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri url = request.Url;            
        if (url.ToString().StartsWith("tel:") || url.ToString().StartsWith("wtai:"))
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.Open(UtilityXam.Contact.GetPhoneFromHTML(url.ToString()));
            return true;
        }else if (url.ToString().StartsWith("mailto:"))
        {
            UtilityXam.Contact xE = new UtilityXam.Contact();
            string xEmail = UtilityXam.Contact.GetEmailFromHTML( url.ToString());
            var xTask = xE.SendEmail("","",new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(){ xEmail });
            return true;
        }
        else if (url.ToString().StartsWith("sms:"))
        {
            UtilityXam.Contact xE = new UtilityXam.Contact();
            string xPh = UtilityXam.Contact.GetPhoneFromHTML(url.ToString());
            var xTask = xE.SendSMS("", "", new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { xPh });
        }
        else
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url.ToString());
        }
        view.SetDownloadListener(new CrmDownloadListener(_context));
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does this [solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101573/open-webview-links-in-external-browser-if-target-is-set-to-blank) answers your question. Detect the url and check if there is target=blank.

Comment: I already found and i already try this solution, and it didn't works for me.
I add in navigated event the JS function and evaluate it by webview.
The event navigating is not fired when i click on target _blank anchor.

My question is, why, the event is not fired?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Does the event fired when click other urls instead of target _blank anchor.

Comment: Yes the other URL non target _blank is fired, and  the navigating event is in Xamarin.Forms.  
I also have a renderer in Xamarin.Android, and i init the webview in Element changed event, i enable support for multiple windows , i also add a custom chromeclient and a custom webview in order to add javascript function to invoke c#.

Comment: In your custom CrmWebViewClient, can you have a try to overload ShouldOverrideUrlLoading or OnLoadResource method to check if these methods fires when open a url with target _blank.

Comment: ShouldOverrideUrlLoading is not fired on achor with target =_blank.

i dont know if this can help, but this JS code rise all events normally:
window.open('https://www.mysite.it', '_blank');

Comment: So can you use this JS code to solve your problem?

Comment: yes i can try change all the link in my site because is in ASP.NET, this is why i change the agent header when it run in my webview.
But i dont like this solution, and i want understand why the anchor link dont work with target=_blank.

Comment: Can you please have a try with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009995/android-webview-links-to-same-window-with-target-blank-to-open-new-window)? It's a native answer and I can help you to translate it to c# if you need.  BTW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713069/why-is-wkwebview-not-opening-links-with-target-blank/25853806#25853806) is also a iOS related thread.

Comment: <3 thank you! in this way it works.
My mistake was exactly not manage the new window event.
I really appreciate your patience and your support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the great help of Jack Hua i'm able to solve the problem.
In OnElementChanged of Hybrid renderer i set support for multiple windows.

```
Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

and next i had to menage onCreateWindow event in the custom chrome webview.
Here the code converted in c# from the link suggested by Jack.

```
        public override bool OnCreateWindow(Android.Webkit.WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Android.OS.Message resultMsg)
    {
        Android.Webkit.WebView newWebView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
        view.AddView(newWebView);
        Android.Webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (Android.Webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.Obj;
        transport.WebView = newWebView;
        resultMsg.SendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer later (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: This opens the new window in chrome and not in the in app browser

Comment: Do I need to create a `HybridWebView` for implementing this solution?

Comment: I'm trying this solution. In my custom `WebView` code I try to do the `OnCreatedWindow` override, but I get the following error: `CS0115 'HybridWebViewRenderer.OnCreateWindow(WebView, bool, bool, Message)': no suitable method found to override`. Any idea how it can get solved?

Answer (score 2):

This is an introduced bug in Xamarin Forms since v4.8.0.1364 (According to the bug report at least)

You can work around it for now by removing the `target="_blank"` from the url or by setting a property

```
webView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

I have fixed it for our app by striping `target="_blank"` and `target='_blank'` in some replacement logic that already runs over the content

There are multiple open issues reporting it for Xamarin Forms github

[[Bug] Cannot open URLs with WebView android when the target is _blank #12917](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12917)

[[Bug] Android WebView's Navigating and Navigated events not fired #12852](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12852)

Comment: Those links to the GitHub issue were invaluable; instead of `SetSupportMultipleWindows(true)`, setting it to **false** made all of the `target="_blank"` links start firing through my `Navigating` event

Answer (score 2):

I tried a completely different approach, because the above answers didn't really help (my target _blank links would always open in a new chrome instance and not in the in-app browser).

First, you'll need to set SetSupportMultipleWindows to false. As soon as you do that, all the windows will open in the same webView:

```
Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
```

More information on how you set these settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Next, all I did was change the back-button behaviour, to make sure the back button doesn't close the app and instead navigates the webview pages (HybridWebView is my custom webview that I created in the first step).

```
    HybridWebView _browser;
    public MainPage()
    {
        _browser = new HybridWebView
        {
            Source = "https://brandschutzplaner-stahltragwerke.promat.ch"
        };

        Content = _browser;
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {

        base.OnBackButtonPressed();

        if (_browser.CanGoBack)
        {
            _browser.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
```