# xamarin forms webview not responding to _blank links in android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a xaml form with webview.  In android the links that have target="_blank" associated with them no longer fire the navigation events.  I've read that it's because of changes in the android webview implementation.  I have found solutions for xamarin android apps but not for xamarin forms apps.
how can i enable _blank links to reach webview events in xamarin forms? i am using this events:

```
webView.Navigated += OnNavigatedHandler;
webView.Navigating += OnNavigatingHandler;
```

Comment: I find some threads about this problem at github: [thread1](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12917) and [thread2](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12852), but you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610409/xamarin-android-webview-dont-fire-navigating-if-target-blank).