# How to check if I am clicking an external link and open it from a site opened in a webview on xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hyperlink

I open my site through a webview, inside the page there are links with the tag <_blank>, but the application treats them as if they were not inside the webview (if it wants them to be pdf links).
I tried to check around but I can't find anything that suits me.
I saw that I can use the BrowserLaunchMode function, but I go back to the starting point because I don't know how to implement it in the webview and above all I don't know how to make the app recognize that I'm clicking a link.
Could someone please tell me if there is a way to check when I touch the webview if I am clicking a link please?

Comment: So you load a website inside a web view on one of your app pages? Then when you click a link inside the web view you want to know if you are clicking a link and launch an external browser?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#events

Comment: @CodingLumis inside the webview I click on a link that should lead to a page that downloads a pdf

Comment: @DavideTramontano and when you click that link does it not download the PDF? I'm trying to understand what behaviour you want.

Comment: i wish that when i click on the link i download the pdf, but nothing happens

Comment: how about the document above

Comment: I'm trying to use the navigating, but with all the links that have the _blank target it doesn't even check

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610409/xamarin-android-webview-dont-fire-navigating-if-target-blank