# WebView loads a google form, link in google form does not open

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview where I perfectly load a google form. In the google form there is a link that redirect to a web page, something like "https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.mywebsite.com/support/" but no matter what I do I cannot open this link. Everything else work fine.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = supportWebPageWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    supportWebPageWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
             }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

The only way to make it work is open the link in a browser.
Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: What are the values of the ```ulr``` in the ```shouldOverrideUrl...``` ?

Comment: Is this one "https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.mywebsite.com/support/"

Comment: Do you get a call for ```onPageFinished``` ?

Comment: No, actually I don't

Comment: The ```shouldOverrideUrl..``` is called multiple times for the same URL ? The one with ```mywebsite...```.

Comment: No the method is called just once

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed that clicking on the link it opens a new window, the answer is than here [Android - Open target _blank links in WebView with external browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser)