# webview open target _blank in new fragment tab

Tags: java, android

i try to open target _blank from   onCreateWindow of WebChromeClient from this post

[Android - Open target _blank links in WebView with external browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser)

but data returns null.

example site getintopc.com

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg)
        {
            WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
            String data = result.getExtra();

            models.add(models.size() - 1, new WebpageModel(DEFAULT_TITLE,
                    data));
            navDrawerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            fragments.add(WebpageFragment.newInstance(fragments.size(),
                    models.get(models.size() - 2).getUrl()));
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .hide(fragments.get(current_position))
                    .add(R.id.container, fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1))
                    .commit();
            current_position = fragments.size() - 1;


            return false;
        }
```

guys i found this project working.

http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2014/04/understanding-androids-webchromeclient.html?m=1

it creates new webview with the url of  target _blank .
but the problem is i can't get the url. I only want the url since i am opening it with the same webview of different fragment tabs.

example i tested getintopc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally a little tips from at the bottom of this question

[Android - Open target _blank links in WebView with external browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser)

```
          mWebView.getSettings().
setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView 
view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message 
resultMsg)
        {

            WebView newView = new 
WebView(getActivity());
            WebSettings settings = 
newView.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

settings.
setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            settings.
setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
            newView.setWebViewClient(new 
WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean 
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urls) {
                    models.add(models.size() - 1, 
new WebpageModel(DEFAULT_TITLE,
                            urls));

navDrawerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



 fragments.
 add(WebpageFragment.newInstance(fragments.size(),

 models.get(models.size() - 2).getUrl()));

 getActivity().
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

.hide(fragments.get(current_position))
                            .add(R.id.container, 
 fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1))
                            .commit();
                    current_position = 
fragments.size() - 1;


                    return true;
                }


            });

            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = 
 (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();



            return true;
        }
```

but when i press download button in getintopc.com unlike other browser it will wait few seconds and create new tab and give me the file to be download instantly instead of going to processing download and wait few seconds page.

for other site with target _blank works fine!